# How do I generate new columns using pandas groupby & aggregate?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame on which I run:

```
df.groupby(by="mycol").agg({"colA": "sum", "colB": "count"})
```

However, `colA` and `colB` need to exist. What is the most "pandaic" approach to creating new columns from an aggregation?

Edit:

Basically, I have a set of columns and my aggregations are not a 1:1 mapping. Thus, consider an example where I would want to aggregate the ratio of two columns' values as a new column. Now think of a dictionary of such mappings.

I know that, in the example, I could just filter for `play` and then compute the mean on the grouped data. But that's not the point of the question, so please ignore this simple solution which is just a side effect of the simple example.

```
>> df
    outlook   play  temperature
0     sunny   True           25
1     sunny   True           25
2  overcast   True           19
3      rain  False           21
4  overcast  False           33
5      rain  False           27
6      rain  False           22
7  overcast   True           26
8     sunny   True           13
9     sunny   True           16

# should become:
>> df.groupby(by="outlook").agg(?)
         play_mean_temp
sunny    19.75
overcast 22.50
rain     NaN
```

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby(by="mycol").agg(['sum','count'])` ?

Comment: Can you add sample of data and desired output?

Comment: @jezrael added as desired. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample you can use:

```
print (df.groupby(by="outlook").apply(lambda x: x.ix[x.play, 'temperature'].mean()))
outlook
overcast    22.50
rain          NaN
sunny       19.75
```

If use firstly boolean indexing, some rows are omit:

```
print (df[df.play].groupby(by="outlook")['temperature'].mean())
outlook
overcast    22.50
sunny       19.75
Name: temperature, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That's wonderful. One more thing: If I have two aggregations, how would I get them into one DataFrame? You got me a series here, but let's say I have two of these aggregations from the same raw data. What would I do?

Comment: Then you can use custom function and return new `DataFrame`, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply).

Comment: Ah! That's it! I didn't think of generating a new DataFrame in `apply`. Nice.

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Maybe helful can be my [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36272611/2901002), although it return Series.